# How to put the 3D objects over the points in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, point

I have a point group containing a field named "Type" and 3D objects with the same type. I would like to place these 3D objects on top of points with the same type automatically in ArcGIS Pro. Is there any way to do that? for example: tools or ArcPy code in ArcGIS Pro.

[image]

I would like to place for example the blue 3D object with type "Lake" over all of the points with type "Lake"

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question with a graphic to explain what you mean by "place these 3D objects on top of points".

Comment: I've already edited the question.

Comment: I was thinking a possible solution would be copy and paste but that would lead to all your 3D cubes having the same orientation, would that be something you want, if not, how are you determining orientation of your cube?

Comment: Do you suggest any solutions for this?